# Capture Image Orientation Issue

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

This is regarding image orientation when captured with the device rotation lock on.'

```
self.photoOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)?.videoOrientation = self.stillImageOrientation
```

I have self.stillImageOrientation listening to status bar orientation

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
```

However, when the user activates device rotation lock and rotates the device, captured photos get saved in the wrong orientation.

I expected this might solve the issue:

```
UIDevice.current.orientation
```

That also stops changing after the device rotation lock.

I noticed the native camera app still registers proper orientation even after the device rotation lock.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Edit your question and show your code where you are generating your image data representation and writing it to disk.

Comment: Have you tried `UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`?

Comment: Ths main issue here is, UIDevice.current.orientation completely stops when the user activates the rotation lock.